# Getting models in nested collections in Backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm working in a collection that contains a model with collections of "itself". For example:

```
[{
     id: 1
     name: "John",
     children: [
         {
              id: 32
              name: "Peter",
              children: []
         },
         {
              id: 54
              name: "Mary",
              children: [
                  {
                      id:12,
                      name: "Kevin"
                  }
         ]
         },
     ]
}]
```

Let say that I want to get the Kevin "user" by its Id. But all that I have is the "first collection". How can I do that?? And about setting a user within a collection? Another thing: Its possible to get all the Kevin "parents" from him? Like Mary and John?

Does anyone has come to a issue like that?

Thanks a LOT

Answer (score 0):

Underscore (which is a Backbone dependency, so you already have it) is great for this sort of thing; if you use its "map" function (which Backbone provides as a method on Collection) with its find function, you can do the following:

```
findPersonInPeopleCollection: function(nameWeAreLookingFor) {
    function findChildren(person) {
        if (!person.children) return [person];
        var children = _.map(person.children, function(child) {
            foundPeople.push(findChildren(child);
        })
        return _.flatten(children);
    }
    var allPeople = _.flatten(myCollectionOfPeople.map(findChildren));
    return _(allPeople).find(function(person) {
        return person.get('name') == nameWeAreLookingFor;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to store the parents initially you could either add logic to your "Person" model class's initialize function, eg.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.each(this.get('children'), function(child) {
            child.parent = this;
        }, this);
    }
 });
```

You could also do something similar by overriding your collection's add method, or adding an event handler to it that triggers after people get added.

Comment: "Although it would probably make more sense to just set the parent property of the children when they first get added to the collection, rather than doing it every time you look up a person." How could I do that? And would work if I wanted to get all its parents?

Comment: The map function is itterating only on the first level ( just getting John and Peter ). Not going "deeper".

Comment: Gah; that was supposed to be recursive, but I failed.  I don't have time to write the recursive version ATM, but I answered your other question in an edited version of my answer, and I'll try and get the recursive version in shortly.

Comment: Ok, the latest version is now recursive.  The code is still un-tested, so I make no guarantees, but if nothing else this should give you a basic idea of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've made a recursive function on the User's Collection that seems to solved the problem for now ( the best of this is that I can use for retrieve a "deep" model and change it.). Something like that ( if someone has any suggestions, be free to give it a opinion ):

```
findUserById: function(id) {
        var self = new Backbone.Collection(this.toJSON());

        return thisCollection(id, this);

        function thisCollection(id, collection, array) {
            var innerSelf = collection || this;
            var thisArray = array || [];
            for(var i = innerSelf.models.length; i--;) {
                if(innerSelf.models[i].get('id') == id) {
                    return [innerSelf.models[i]].concat([thisArray]);
                }else {
                    if(innerSelf.models[i].get('children').length > 0) {
                        thisArray.push(innerSelf.models[i]);
                        return thisCollection(id, innerSelf.models[i].get('children'), thisArray);
                    }else {
                        innerSelf.remove(innerSelf.models[i]);
                        return thisCollection(id, self, []);
                    }   

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Basically I return an array with 2 items. The first is the record that I'm looking for and the second is an array with the parents of this user.